# Argument ruby error - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my model class

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
 attr_accessor :address, :category,:name,:postcode,:tel

 def initialize(result)

   @address = result["address"]
   @category = result["category"]
 end
end
```

In my controller  I am doing create Location object in two ways

```
Location.new(result) #works fine
@post.location.new         #get error
```

Why in second case its looking for constructor with 2 arguments. I also added constructor with two arguments but it didnt work.

I get error

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Edit :
How do i make @post.location.new work ?

Comment: It is looking for one argument, not two. You only gave none, then two. "x for y" means "there is actually x where y is expected".

Comment: @post.location.new doesnt have any argument.. i just want an empty object.

Comment: What do you want the values to be when you do not give the argument?

Comment: Does `location = @post.build_location` also error out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the constructor for `Location` to take exactly one argument, so now you'll have to provide it with each call of `new`. Your best bet is probably not to do that, or at least to provide a default, something like this:

```
def initialize(result = {})
   @address  = result["address"]
   @category = result["category"]
end
```

To build an empty association, you can then use

```
@post.build_location
```

or

```
@post.location = Location.new
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for the last part of your question, ( 2 for 1 ) means you provided two, but the method only takes one.  Try only one.